# Reach a total score from user input into prompts

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to write a javscript code to keep track of score for a game. Im trying to have the code prompt for user input and loop the prompt until the user reaches a score of 300.

What I can't figure out is how to have it prompt add the scores together in the loop until it reaches 300.

```
    while (totscore < 300 );
{
      totscore = parseInt(window.prompt("Keep entering score until reaching 300",0));
```

After that Im not sure of where to get with the code.

Comment: Try `+=` instead of `=`, right now you're always assigning new score to `totscore` variable instead of adding to it.

Comment: And there shouldn't be `;` on your first line.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.

Initialize `totscore` to zero and run the loop while adding prompt input. Remove trailing `;` after `while` loop. Or else, it will end before loop body begins.

> Is there also a way to see how many input the user made so I could then use that to divide there final score and create an average? Would it just be count++

```
let totscore = 0, count = 0;

while (totscore < 300) {  
    totscore += parseInt(window.prompt("Enter score here:", 0)); 
    count++;
}

console.log("Total inputs: " + count);
console.log("Average: " + (totscore / count));
```

@OP since you're new to this community, few suggestions:-

1. Put appropriate tags. Java tag is incorrect.
2. Format code correctly to make it easier to read.
3. Learn basics of JS programming. [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you I was having a tough time find the += while googling.

Answer (score -1):

```
        let totscore = 1;
while (totscore < 300 );
{
      totscore = parseInt(window.prompt("Keep entering score until reaching 300",totscore));
      totscore++;      

}
```

Comment: Did you read the question correctly? OP wants to take prompt input and add it to the total score.